# Best way to Sync data from SQL Server to SQLite in WPF app

Tags: sql-server, wpf, sqlite, synchronization, zumero

I am working on a project where the client is occasionally connected. The client app is being developed in WPF and uses a SQLite database. My plan is to create a central SQL Server database and when the clients connect to a network they can send the data to SQL server.

I have looked at several of the available packages such as [Zumero](http://zumero.com/) and [sql-lite sync](http://sqlite-sync.com/) but I am not sure if either of them is the right tool for the job.

Just to summarize, my requirements are:

- Sync client must work well from within a 64 bit WPF app
- Client will need to present a sync status dialog. Perhaps even a conflict resolution screen.
- Centralized database will be SQL Server 2012 or greater
- Sync framework should provide ability to update schema without minimal effort.

Does anyone have a recommendation of how I should proceed? Your advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you took a look at MS Sync Framework https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt490616.aspx?

Comment: The only stumbling block from Zumero's point of view is that *all* conflict resolution happens on the server. Ping us at support@zumero.com if you have questions about how ZSS might work for you.

Comment: @VasylZvarydchuk I did look at MS Sync Framework. Seems like the project has been abandoned which makes me apprehensive about starting a new project with it.

Comment: What framework did you choose for your need? I am looking for a good framework like this for Android.

Comment: After extensive review of 3rd party packages and their associated problems I came to the conclusion that there was nothing commercially available that I considered reliable. I could have built something myself but it would have been extremely time consuming and still not 100% bulletproof. I presented the option to the client to either spend the development hours on the real business logic or on a sync framework. After some discussion they decided to abandon the "occasionally connected" architecture and go for a "always connected" version instead.

Comment: You should take a look at https://github.com/Mimetis/Dotmim.Sync Maybe your question is too old now, but just in case ...